# HTTP command not giving me forwarding URLs

Tags: ngrok

Trying to use *grok to test out retrieving web hook requests from a third-party vendor, but when I try to use:

> ngrok http 5001

I do not even get any UI response from *ngrok*. I have checked around this site, and other articles, and all of them were getting their forwarding URLs to use.

I tried working with the `--log` and `--log-info` arguments, but still nothing outputting in *bash*.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm on a Windows 10 machine when doing this, and it seems like the Git BASH terminal does not seem to work well. Though, the command prompt did worked well. Perhaps because the file was an .exe might explain it.